# Jquery : Hide first row of all the tables except first table

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have many tables like

```
 <table class="mytable">
<tr class = "first_tr">
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
<tr class = "second_tr">
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
<tr class = "third_tr">
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
 </table>

<table class="mytable">
<tr class = "first_tr">
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
<tr class = "second_tr">
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
<tr class = "third_tr">
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
 </table>
```

i may have more than 10 such tables

i need to hide the first row (class name `first_tr`) of all the tables except first table

Comment: The title says "hide second row" and the body says "hide the first row"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can exclude the first element using `.not()` method:

```
$('table.mytable').not(':first').find('.first_tr').hide();
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
$('td:nth-child(2):not(:first)').hide();
```

### [**Demo here**](http://jsfiddle.net/PSm9J/)

**More info about what I used:**

- [**:nth-child()**](http://api.jquery.com/nth-child-selector/)
- [**:not()**](http://api.jquery.com/not-selector/)
- [**:first**](http://api.jquery.com/first-selector/)

Answer (score 0):

You can use [.not()](http://api.jquery.com/not/) selector

```
$('.mytable').not(":eq(0)").find(".first_tr").hide()
```

Or, You can use [.gt()](http://api.jquery.com/gt-selector/) selector

```
$('.mytable:gt(0)').find(".first_tr").hide()
```

If you want to hide **second row** use `second_tr` instead of `first_tr`

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this as simple as that:

```
$('.first_tr', '.mytable').not(':first').hide();
```

[Demo 1](http://jsfiddle.net/C5349/)

Or, within the same selector:

```
$('.first_tr', '.mytable:not(:first)').hide();
```

[Demo 2](http://jsfiddle.net/C5349/1/)